# Python | замена символов

Tags: python, строки

Всем привет, допустим у меня есть строка

print('hello world')

как мне в этой строки заменить print(' ') Не меняя содержимого

Comment: А на что вы хотите заменить print? Сделать это можно по-разному, например, с помощью регулярных выражений.

Comment: @Bol4onok display[hello world], примерно такого вывода я хочу добится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, один из вариантов реализации:

```
import re

pattern = r'print\(([^\)]*)\)'

repl = r'display[\1]'

string = 'print(\'Hello world\')'

answer = re.sub(pattern, repl, string)

print(answer)
```

Вывод

```
display['Hello world']
```